# floating an image over other divs, from the right

Tags: layout, internet-explorer-7, css-float, html

I've read many other posts regarding floating divs, but haven't been able to find success yet with the things I've tested, so here I am... (I'm still new to this, so apologies if my code isn't super clean!)

I have an image that I'd like to float over several others. My goal (if it is attainable) is to have it in a fixed position from the upper right corner of .container. I'm close... but I can't get the image to move in from the right, and as it sits now, it is bumping the other photo out of the header (without the .crosses added, it sits in the green, right-aligned.)

The project requires that it still looks good (or degrades nicely) in IE7.

I've set up a fiddle here: (can't figure out what the red error means by "links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code") so, if you could just go there and visit: 
http://jsfiddle.net/cathi/VAkk5/5/

HTML (extract):

```
<div class="container">

<div class="crosses"><img src="/img/common/crosses-motif.png" width="213" height="118" alt="crosses-motif" /></div>

<div class="header"></div>
 <div class="hero">
    <div class="herophoto">photo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (extract):

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.crosses {
    float:right;
    margin-right:0;
        margin-top:130px;
}

.header {
    height: 150px;
}

.headerlogo {
    width: 250px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float:left;

}

.headerlogo2 {
    float:right;
}

.hero {
    height: 205px;
}

.heroheadline {
    height: 0;
    width: 450px;
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-left: 70px;
    float:left;
}

.herophoto {
    height: 205px;
    width: 333px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: (it's also pushing "logo2" to the left, when it should be right-aligned also.)

Comment: The warning means that you should also copy-paste the relevant parts of the code right into your question. A good advice for newcomers: always read the rules/faq/documentation before proceeding.